# Write a 2d-list without the same number of columns in Excel with xlwgins

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm trying in a Excel's workbook write a text file like this:

> 14807         2010 
>    2    0   ""   -1    0   0
>    0 
>   Joints
>    0 
>   Frames
>    3200 
>    1    0    0    0    0   "1"    0   ""    0    0    .15    .9    0   ""    1.1    28    0    0    0    .3    .3    0
>    1    0    0    0    0   "2"    0   ""    0    0    .15    .9    0   ""    1.1    28    0    0    0    .3    .3    0
>    1    0    0    0    0   "3"    0   ""    0    0    .15    .9    0   ""    1.1    28    0    0    0    .3    .3    0
>    1    0    0    0    0   "1"    0   ""    0    0    .15    .9    0   ""    1.1    28    0    0    0    .3    .3    0

The idea is write each value in different Cell. How can I do that efficiently ?. I have this but doesn't work:

```
import xlwings as xw

filename = "Viguetas de N+47.00 a N+145.80.dcc"
dc_cad = DC_CAD(filename)
dc_cad.show_data()

class DC_CAD:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.data = self.getData()
        print(self.data[:5])

        self.excel_app = xw.App(visible = False, add_book = False, impl = None)  # impl ?
        self.wb = self.excel_app.books.add()
        self.sh = self.wb.sheets[0]
        self.sh.range("A1").value = self.data

    def getData(self):
        return [line.split(' ') for line in open(self.filename, 'r').read().split('\n')]

    def show_data(self):
        self.excel_app.visible = True
```

Comment: Use a CSV (comma separated values) format most libraries including numpy and pandas will handle it

Comment: Maybe, but I need continue to work with Excel, then, is better use a CSV library or continue to use xlwigns ? Thank you.

Comment: You can use csv in excel

Comment: With CSV librari is possible save each value in each cell ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution but is really slow:

```
class DC_CAD:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.data = self.getData()

        self.excel_app = xw.App(visible = False, add_book = False, impl = None)  # impl ?
        self.wb = self.excel_app.books.add()
        self.sh = self.wb.sheets[0]
        rng = self.sh.range("A1")
        for i, line in enumerate(self.data[0:10]):
            rng.offset(i, 0).value = line

    def getData(self):
        return [' '.join(filter(None, line.split(' '))).split(' ') for line in open(self.filename, 'r').read().split('\n')]

    def show_data(self):
        self.excel_app.visible = True
```